# creating a sortable grid in Cocoa (horizontally)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, sorting, user-interface

I'm struggling to create some view with sortable elements in it.

What I'm looking for is to have some elements, like 1-5 in one row, so that I can then drag them left and right and rearrange them, while also adding and deleting.

Like this, first row (1 2 3 4): [jQuery sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid)

Inside these elements I want to have a view, like some more controls, and changeable items. TableViews seem to only sort vertically, and the CollectionView doesn't really do that either, as far as I know.

Are there any implementations where I could have a look? What would be the approach here?

Thanks in advance!
Chris

Comment: You should try collection view , I think it's properly for creating grid cells.

Comment: I did, but it doesn't really support those dragging functionality. I also didn't find any tutorial or sample using CollectionView

Comment: check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713111/uicollectionview-effective-drag-and-drop).

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem once and haven't found nothing Cocoa for that purpose. 
In principle thsi should help:

Use an NSMutableDictionary with Keys for each field, e.g. field_1 and a value, that contains the positionnr in the CollectionView. When reordering adjust the values to the change.

The data for the collectionView is an NSMutableArray, that is created/updated by using the number to display from the dictionary = value. An array can contain any data, also other array, and is used for the CollectionView.

Comment: Thanks, but the logic is not the problem, more the dragging behaviour of the control.